# What's the name of the horizontal menu specific to Windows 10 apps and how to implement it?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone

I'm talking about that menu type where you can see the next element peek out on the right and u need to slide the screen to right so u can move to it.
Exapmle: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9AO6.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. How does your question pertain to programming? With editing, your question _might_ fit on another SE site.

Comment: Well I asked for the implementation too, but if you think it doesn't fit here then please tell me and I will remove it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to the [Panorama Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941104%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for which there are multiple [sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941109%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) out on the net to give you in depth tutorials and examples of usage and tricks. You can find Win10 specifics starting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt244352.aspx)

One example of which (taken directly from the docs);

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <controls:Panorama Title="my application">

      <!--Panorama item one-->
      <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
         <Grid/>
       </controls:PanoramaItem>

       <!--Panorama item two-->
       <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
          <Grid/>
       </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

As Richard pointed out though, your question doesn't show much effort made before your inquiry and doesn't directly correlate to a specific question about programming and leans more towards just searching for a feature.

However, since it's your first day on SO hopefully this helps and in the future you might browse the FAQ for some basic guidelines of the site to avoid any issues moving forward. Welcome and it really is an excellent resource support by a lot of great individuals helping each other out. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. From now on I will not post anything that's not 100% related to programming or debugging, I know it's a great community and I also would like to help it grow.

Comment: Eh no worries, most of us got down-votes and stuff starting out too, don't take it personally, we've all been there. Glad you got a remedy and good luck!